# Need help with: "file type Gzip archive is not supported"

Tags: downloads, zip, gzip, unzip

I’ve downloaded the Ltc core wallet on Ubuntu 16.04, 32bit. When I try opening the folder, a message tells me ‘file type Gzip archive is not supported’. So I downloaded Xarchiver and tried again, with the same result. Thoughts, anybody? And yes: I’m a bit of a noob.

Comment: Please specify the folder that you tried to open...

Comment: Did you try "Open With other Application" and select Xarchiver?

Comment: @EODCraft: That's what I first tried, yes. Downloaded Xarchiver, but it didn't do the trick. But, as indicated below, an automatic update solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The file is surely gzip-compressed.

Uncompress it using command line:

```
craft@engine:~$ gunzip thefile.gz
```

Note: The original file will be removed and replaced by the uncompressed one.

If it says something like program not installed or unknown command, install it via:

```
craft@engine:~$ sudo apt-get install gzip
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out asap and let know if it worked...

Comment: First thing I did when switching on the 'puter was install a service pack and after, the download opened as smooth as ever. So, the problem solved itself. But thanks for coming to the rescue anyhow!